# Identify object that pass through a hole?

Tags: sensor, rfid, bluetooth-low-energy, proximity-sensor

We have small bags in 2 different colors that pass through a hole of about 40cm. The bags can be dropped and so they pass very fast.
We have to know which kind passed through the hole.

I was looking for many ways that will keep the bags passive without batteries.

This is commercial and many bags will be manufactured.

Here are the ways I see, would be happy to hear your opinion.

1. Bad: color identification which will not be accurate at sun/dark.
2. Ok: RFID passive tags inside the bags and a coil around the hole, problem is that the coil used to detect them has to mechanically be installed very precisely into the hole. Also, the speed of identification is slow(?) and the tech is pretty old.
3. ok: Bluetooth beacons inside the bags which will require battery inside the bag, and the tags are pretty expensive.( Estimote, Kontakt)
4. NFC which is still new and there are not many solutions ready yet.
5. Camera with advanced AI .

Which seems reasonable? any specific manufacturers for these?

Comment: IR detection could work maybe? you could have IR reflective surface, or even detect different colours using IR because of the fact that different colours reflect IR differently

Comment: I've used this chip before http://www.vishay.com/docs/84150/vcnl3020.pdf
using that + black and white surface would work a charm

Comment: What makes you rule out colour identification? Is it not possible to control environmental light intensity somehow — e.g. by adding controlled lighting?

Comment: Color sensors are very sterile, too much light or darkness and you get bad results. Infra red can only tell that something had passed, hoe can it work with colors?

Comment: @Makoto This sensor is not relevant at all, i need to identify different colors.

Comment: @Curnelious sorry for not making it clear. The sensor reflects differently off different colour surfaces regardless of ambient light.

Comment: Please specify the environmental constrains: transportable, vibrations, direct sunlight / artificial light, dust, humidity, EM interference, noise... Further specify the material of the "bags" and how it might change. And define bag (backpak, shopping bag, handbag, waste bag, mailbag, bin bag, ....)

Comment: @Curnelious: please don't rule out possible implementations beforehand. There might be ways to do this with color detection even in bright sunlight.

Comment: The falling object can trigger a strobe light. The strobe light will brightly illuminate the object. A camera can capture an the brightly illuminated object. With the strobe light, I think the image will be good enough to determine object color with very simple image procesing.

Comment: If device-in-bag is a viable option, presumably someone will need to take device-out-of-bag, so why not sort manually in the first place

Comment: Modulated lighting is the standard way to distinguish reflected light from uncontrolled ambient light, see nasha, try-catch and mkeith comments. Tune your receiver to look only at the strobe modulation, and ignore the DC ambient.

Answer (score 2):

As you've got objects of different color, it should be possible to use a simple color sensor. For example, [TCS34725](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1334).

Comment: Thanks a lot i read about it and it seems promising, only thing you can't find in the data sheet is respond time. I wonder if i can get something around the 1-5ms from the moment i ask for results ( I want to measure color only when I sense a bag, to minimize error)

Comment: Also I wonder how much light we need, does it work in darkness?

Comment: Of course it does need light. That's why Adafruit sells the module with color sensor and a white LED. They also specify the color temperature of that LED, to get consistent results.

Comment: For the measuring time, you should probably just try it yourself and see if it works in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RFiD with ISO 15693 protocol tags (NXP I-code SLI or Tagsys).
It's a RFiD HF technology, the tags are long range detection and the read timing is short.
There are multiple form factor for the tags with different size.
The antenna could be around the hole and then the position of the tag can't be critical.